# Android Navigation Component: How to add a destination programmatically?

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-architecture-navigation

I want to inject a new destination to the current nav graph.

I notice `NavGraph` has a method `void addDestination(@NonNull NavDestination node)` but I can't find a proper way to create a `NavDestination` and navigate to it using `navController.navigate(R.id.new_dest_id)`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've got two working ways:

```
navController.graph.addDestination(ActivityNavigator(this).createDestination().apply {
    id = R.id.new_dest
    setComponentName(ComponentName(context, NewActivity::class.java))
    // or setIntent
})
```

or this

```
navController.graph.addDestination(
    navController.navigatorProvider.getNavigator(ActivityNavigator::class.java)
        .createDestination().apply {
            id = R.id.new_dest
            setComponentName(ComponentName(context, NewActivity::class.java))
        }
)
```

There is also a DSL builder `ActivityNavigatorDestinationBuilder`.

Fragment is similar. Change `ActivityNavigator` to `FragmentNavigator` and use different setters.

I also made a mistake when I added a destination in one graph and tried to navigate to the new destination in another graph. of course that never work.

Comment: I'm having a similar problem. I want to navigate to a new graph which already has its fragments configured. I was able to create a new destination with NavGraphNavigator, but this creates a completely new graph how do I inflate the one I already have?

Comment: @VictorPetrovski You'd better ask a new question about it. BTW, `NavInflater` seems promising.

Comment: Thanks, I already managed to do it. Your code for adding destination gave me a pretty clear picture on how to accomplish what I've wanted!!

Comment: do we have java equivalent of this code?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to pass the ID of your newly created Destination in navigate(), like `navigate(myDes.getId())`